# Solving a functional equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

Suppose I have two functions `f[x,y,z]` and `g[x,y,z]`, both analytically defined. I want to solve for a function `H` (assuming that it exists) such that `f[x,y,z] = H[g[x,y,z]]` .

Is there a way in *Mathematica* that I could solve for the `H` function?

Comment: Would you have a more specific example in mind?

Comment: @MarcoB  Say `f[x, y] = x*y, g[x, y] = (x*y)^2` and I want to find a `H[x] = x^2`. I'm working on Heston Model and the functions are extremely complicated, so I didn't quote them here and asked the question in a general way.

Comment: Define `H = (f[x, y, z]/g[x, y, z]) # &`.  Then. `H[g[x, y, z]]` yields `f[x, y, z]`.  Probably not satisfying, however.

Comment: You might look into `SolveAlways` but you'll still need to specify some kind of model form of the function `H` for the parameters of which you'll need to solve.

Comment: If `H` is a polynomial then yes, it can be done using polynomial elimination methods. Otherwise I suspect more elaborate methods will be needed, assuming it can be done algorithmically at all.